# Is changing the oil in a Jetta TDI something a non-mechanic can do?

Tags: vw, maintenance

I always change my own oil, newer or older car.  I have been looking at the Jetta TDI, 2015+.  They are pretty good buys (I'm in the US, if that matters.)

I have read this,

[What is the cost of general maintenance on VW Jetta TDI (diesel)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/what-is-the-cost-of-general-maintenance-on-vw-jetta-tdi-diesel)

But I've never owned a German car.  Can you do things like oil changes yourself on a German car?  I have always heard, and still do, about all the maintenance required and great expense.

Comment: @alephzero - Please write an answer from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I thought everybody knew that those ingenious German engineers have invented a special system, where a huge robot arm turns the whole car upside down to do oil changes …

Seriously though, VWs are no different from the oil change on any other European car, though I've never changed the oil on an American car, so the OP might be used to something different.

Note that if you use the correct oil grade and type, the manufacturer's oil change interval will be much longer than the 3,000 mile US "rule of thumb"- probably 10,000, but check in your owner's handbook.

This video should answer the question "can I do it myself:"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs47rh2nfUE

Comment: To add to this. Make sure it has proper VW oil spec. Usually found in the manual. Any old oil wont do. You need special low soot oil for DPF to be happy